# Is it possible to use Localytics with Mono for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, localytics

I am new to iPhone developement in general. I am currently using Monotouch (MonoDevelop as the IDE). Is it possible to use Localytics with this for app tracking purposes?

I have seen that there is an [iOS Integration Guide for iPhone and iPad](http://www.localytics.com/docs/iphone-integration/) page, but that uses Xcode, whereas with MonoDevelop, you use Xcode only for interface development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoTouch can use any native library by creating a binding for it.

Here is some documentation about it:

[MonoTouch Native Libraries Made Easy](http://blog.xamarin.com/2011/11/02/monotouch-native-libraries-made-easy/)
[Binding Objective-C Libraries](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Binding_Objective-C_Libraries)

Answer (score 0):

There's a GitHub project by Kevin McMahon which provides [MonoTouch bindings for the Localytics iOS SDK](https://github.com/kevinmcmahon/monotouch-localytics).